# How can I sort an array by number of occurrence of its values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$name_arr = array('raj','raj','ganesh','rahul','ganesh','mayur','raj','rahul');
```

I want to sort it like this:

```
$final_arr = array('raj','raj','raj','ganesh','ganesh','rahul','rahul','mayur');
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple way using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):-

```
$array = array_count_values($name_arr); //get all occurrences of each values
arsort($array);
print_r($array);//print occurrences array
$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $key=>$val){ // iterate over occurrences array
  for($i=0;$i<$val;$i++){ //apply loop based on occurrences number
    $final_array[] = $key; // assign same name to the final array
  }
}

print_r($final_array); // print final array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/847428

Comment: This is computationally expensive - there are simpler solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

simple use `array_count_values` and `array_fill` and `array_merge`

**1st :** array_count_values will get the values presented count as a array like below .

```
Array ( [raj] => 3 [ganesh] => 2 [rahul] => 2 [mayur] => 1 )
```

**2nd :** Apply arsort() . descending order, according to the value

**3rd :** Loop that array and make the new array based on count fill the array using array_fill .

**4th :** Then merge the array .

```
<?php

$name_arr = array('raj','raj','ganesh','rahul','ganesh','mayur','raj','rahul');

$new_arr = array_count_values($name_arr);

arsort($new_arr);

$value=array();

foreach($new_arr as $key=>$val){

   $value= array_merge($value,array_fill(0,$val,$key));
}

print_r($value);

?>
```

Comment: This is computationally expensive - there are simpler solutions for this problem.

Comment: With *n* being the size of the array, you are invoking `array_merge()` and `array_fill()` *n* times.

Comment: No, but it's just not the best solution.

Comment: it's  not best solution as well as it's not wrong solution . @localheinz

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this is by using the built-in functions `array_count_values()` and `usort()`:

```
<?php

$name_arr = array('raj','raj','ganesh','rahul','ganesh','mayur','raj','rahul');

$valueCount = array_count_values($name_arr);

$final_arr = $name_arr;

usort($final_arr, function ($a, $b) use ($valueCount) {
    return $valueCount[$b] - $valueCount[$a];
});

var_dump($final_arr);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/4LXVc

Comment: Since you keep insisting that rebuilding the array is more expensive… not sure repeated invocation of the comparator function is any cheaper.

Comment: Even so, it's still the least amount of code while maintaining a high level of legibility, don't you think, @deceze?

Comment: I certainly agree there, and for small arrays this is preferable regardless of its performance, since it's likely *fast enough*.

Comment: The code does not seem to work properly – the `$final_arr` is not actually sorted by the number of occurrences.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$name_arr = array('raj','raj','ganesh','rahul','ganesh','mayur','raj','rahul');

rsort($name_arr);

print_r($name_arr);
```

Output

```
Array (raj , raj , raj , rahul , rahul, mayur, ganesh, ganesh )
```

Comment: This might work with this particular array, but it doesn't generically solve the problem stated by the original poster. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.rsort.php.